# "System cannot find the file specified" when trying to run PowerShell script

Tags: javascript, powershell, activex, wsh

I am working on a menu that calls PowerShell scripts with `wscript.shell` and ActiveX.  I am passing three variables to `wshshell.Run`:

- `scriptID`, which is the name of a ps1 file,
- `vmName`, which is the name of the virtual machine the script will act on, and
- `checkstate`, which is the state of the checkbox associated with the menu item.

Here is my current non-working code:

```
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("powershell.exe  -file " & scriptID & " " & vmName & " " & checkstate, 7, true);
```

This always produces an error stating "The system cannot find the file specified."

I have tried following the syntax mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351508/using-a-wscript-shell-activex-to-execute-a-command-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687216/running-command-wscript-shell-activex-in-javascript) with no luck.  Both seemed promising but produce the same error I have above.

I tested taking the variables out and just running:

```
WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -file test.ps1", 7, true)
```

which works, but

```
WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -file " & "test.ps1", 7, true)
```

fails.

Comment: I think you already have the answer '&' vs. '+'. So just a note: when calling PowerShell scripts always try to use a full path of the script. -file "c:\tmp\test.ps1" can save a lot of problems with intermittent issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because the string concatenation operator in JavaScript is `+`, not `&`.

Change this:

```
WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -file " & scriptID & " " & vmName & " " & checkstate, 7, true);
```

into this:

```
WshShell.Run("powershell.exe -file " + scriptID + " " + vmName + " " + checkstate, 7, true);
```

Comment: That did it.  After doing a bunch of testing in VB I never even thought they would be the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `Wshell.WorkingDirectory` to the directory where your `test.ps1` is located.

eg:

```vb
wsh = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.Shell");
wsh.workingDirectory = "C:\my\dir\to\psscript";
wsh.run("powershell.exe -file test.ps1", 7, true);
```

Check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae0a4aee(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: The WorkingDirectory property only applies to VBscript. For Javascript, use the CurrentDirectory property.